# Android how to highlight a selection in a list

Tags: android, listview

What I want to do is very simple.

I have a ListFragment filled with items. If I touch one item I want the text or background of the item to change color. This means that this item is selected. Now when I touch another item I want the last item to change back to normal and select the new one.

How can I do this?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:

The solutions that remember the last views work but are dependant on accessing the last view to either set it's state or color. Now this works.

However I have new problem. I also have a function for moving an item up in the list.

Here it is:

```
public void MoveUp(){
    if (lastselected > 0){
        String item = adapter.getItem(lastselected);
        adapter.remove(item);
        adapter.insert(item, lastselected-1);           
        lastselected = lastselected -1;
        System.err.println("Is View NULL " + (getListView().getChildAt(lastselected) == null));
    }
}
```

The problem (And this is why I insisted on "what to do in Unmark" in the second solution proposed) is that for the last items in a 64 item lists the function getChildAt returns null. Since it turns null I can neither set it's selected state nor set it's color back.

This is my debug printout:

```
07-21 18:30:54.490: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL true
07-21 18:30:54.670: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL true
07-21 18:30:54.860: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL true
07-21 18:30:55.020: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL true
07-21 18:30:55.180: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL false
07-21 18:30:55.720: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL false
07-21 18:30:55.930: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL false
07-21 18:30:56.110: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL false
07-21 18:30:56.340: WARN/System.err(6733): Is View NULL false
```

And all I kept doing is pressing the up button. If I can find someway for this function to return a non null pointer it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a Selector [(See StateList)](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/white" />
  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@color/selected_color" />
  <item 
    android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

In the background for your list_item put this which is a reference to the above XML.

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg_selector"
```

Comment: This approach definitely does not work. One reason only there is no state that is state_lastpressed or something like that. I've tried all of the states mentioned but none of them keep the item the selected color after the finger leaves the screen.

Comment: I dont understand, when an item is "state_pressed" its color will change, you can only have one item as state_pressed at a time, correct?

Comment: Correct. But pressed means item being pressed by my finger. After the finger leaves the screen the color reverts.

Comment: The idea is to set the view that gets pressed to "selected" (`View.setSelected(true)`). When another view gets press, set the previous view to not selected and select the new view. You can use a class variable that holds the selected view to keep track of which one is currently selected.

Comment: @jrobinson I see, right, then the selector would work by triggering the "state_selected" state.

Comment: This works. However doing this presents no advantage as far as I can see over simply setting the color programatically as the solution below suggested. Replace TextView.setTextColor for View.setSelected and it is the same solution.

Comment: the advantage is that its cleaner to have presentation logic in your XMLs instead of in your application logic.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`onListItemClick()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) to do that. It is called when one Item is clicked.

You could then change Background/Text color and mark it as highlighted. If you want to safe this state, you could do it using a Field in your class, which holds the selected item's ID (or something).

---

Just a little illustration:

```
public class YourFragment extends ListFragment{

    private long current_id;
    private ListView current_lv;

    public void onListItemClick (ListView l, View v, int position, long id){
        // Check if the fields are initialized:
        if (current_id != null && current_lv != null){
            // Unmark the previously selected entry:
            unmark();
        }
        // Mark the currently selected entry by using the
        // given ListView "l" and long "id"

        // Change the field-values:
        current_id = id;
        current_lv = l;
    }

    private void unmakr(){
        // Take the fields to unmark the entry
    }

}
```

I used the `ListView` and the ID of the entry to determine which one was the previously selected one, you can however use the `View` or something else if you like.

But you should note, which parameters the method gives you.

Comment: The problem with this method is that I can't find a way to access the previously pressed view to change its color back to normal.

Comment: That's when saving the currently selected Entry-ID comes into play. So you'll have the last selected entry-id (and can unmark it) and then change it to the currently selected Entry-ID.

Comment: This I understood. What I meant is that there is no function that is something like getView(last_entry_id). Or At least I can't find it.

Comment: I added some sample-code, maybe this helps you understanding what I mean.

Comment: Something to set the changed text/background-color back to normal so the entry isn't marked anymore. What you have to do there depends on what you do when you mark one as "selected".