# How to higlight multiple items in a list in Android?

Tags: android, listactivity, selected

I have a ListActivity that presents a list of names from a database using a SimpleCursorAdapter.  I want the user to be able to select 1 or more names by clicking them and then proceed to the next Activity.  This should be a toggle, so that if the user clicks a selected name it will become de-selected. The underlying code is working fine, the problem is how to show the user which items are currently selected.

I looked at this solution: [Android how to highlight a selection in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782504/android-how-to-highlight-a-selection-in-a-list) and tried toggling .setSelected() on the TextView for the name.  The problem is that the "selected" state apparently can only be true for one item in a list at a time. So if the user touches "Alice" then "Bob," only "Bob" will show as selected.  Any thoughts on the best way to have a toggle-able highlight for multiple list items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the setChoiceMode method of the AbsListView class and its possible CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE parameter value.